# Ошибка при INSERT запросе в mysql. Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql

Код:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `user`, `password`)
VALUES (1, {}, {})""".format(user, password))
```

Вот что получает мускул:

```
INSERT INTO `accounts`(`id`, `user`, `password`) VALUES (1, asdasd, asd)
```

Ответ:

`1054 - Unknown column 'asdasd' in 'field list'`

Раньше с SQL не работал, понимаю, что вопрос скорее всего глупый, но везде в туториалах показывают именно такие запросы. Я уже час туплю и читаю, но все равно что-то в них косячу и не могу понять что именно.

Comment: Предвижу следующая ошибка - такой id занят.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас нет кавычек вокруг текстовых значений - `'{}'`:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `user`, `password`)
    VALUES (1, '{}', '{}')
""".format(user, password))
```

Но это - опасный подход, ведущий к уязвимостям инъекций в базу.

Безопасно, если используете запрос с параметрами:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `user`, `password`)
    VALUES (1, %s, %s)
""", (user, password))
```

Учтите, что в качестве параметров используется кортеж (tuple)